# Fade out div and fade in next sibling div based on class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically generated set of divs, each one contains an image, text and button. Each div has a class of `timeline-item` and they are all hidden initially apart from the first one.

What I want to do is when the next button is clicked, it will fade out the current timeline-item div and fade in the next one smoothly. Currently it fades out the first one and fades in all the div's with a class of `timeline-item`.

```js
$('.timeline-next').click(function(){
    $(".timeline-item").fadeOut().next(".timeline-item").fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timeline">
    <div class="timeline-menu">
        <h2>Since 1861</h2>
        <div id="timeline-body" class="container">
            <div class="timeline-item visible">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> A RICH RACING HERITAGE</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut magna purus, efficitur
                        in dui vel, euismod mollis lacus. Aliquam ac erat non ligula ultricies commodo
                        aliquet nec eros. Donec efficitur, purus eget volutpat porta, nulla metus rhoncus
                        odio, sit amet cursus libero lectus vitae est. Curabitur cursus velit vitae purus
                        finibus sodales. Ut tincidunt vestibulum suscipit. Nunc auctor turpis in faucibus
                        pulvinar. Nunc non tincidunt magna. Praesent vitae commodo nibh. Nulla a nisl eget
                        ligula pharetra dignissim.
                    </p>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item hidden">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1862</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item hidden">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1863</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item hidden">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1864</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item hidden">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1865</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item hidden">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1861</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item hidden">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1861</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item hidden">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1861</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item hidden">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1861</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item hidden">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1861</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item hidden">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1861</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item hidden">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1861</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item hidden">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1861</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item hidden">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1861</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item hidden">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1861</h3>
                    <p>tdasdsdsdasd</p>
                    <p>asdasdasdas</p>
                    <p>asdaasd</p>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this somewhat what you are looking for? You'll have to comine it with the fadeOut method. http://jsfiddle.net/kmtCV/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the complete callback in order to have a sequential fade:

```js
$('.timeline-next').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this).closest(".timeline-item");
    $this.fadeOut(400, function(){
      $this.next(".timeline-item").fadeIn(400); 
    });
});
```

```css
.timeline-item {
  display: none;
}

.timeline-item.visible {
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timeline">
    <div class="timeline-menu">
        <h2>Since 1861</h2>
        <div id="timeline-body" class="container">
            <div class="timeline-item visible">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> A RICH RACING HERITAGE</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut magna purus, efficitur
                        in dui vel, euismod mollis lacus. Aliquam ac erat non ligula ultricies commodo
                        aliquet nec eros. Donec efficitur, purus eget volutpat porta, nulla metus rhoncus
                        odio, sit amet cursus libero lectus vitae est. Curabitur cursus velit vitae purus
                        finibus sodales. Ut tincidunt vestibulum suscipit. Nunc auctor turpis in faucibus
                        pulvinar. Nunc non tincidunt magna. Praesent vitae commodo nibh. Nulla a nisl eget
                        ligula pharetra dignissim.
                    </p>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1862</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1863</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1864</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1865</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1861</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1861</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1861</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1861</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1861</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1861</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1861</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1861</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1861</h3>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-item">
                <div class="timeline-image">
                    <img src="http://musselburgh.dev/mediaLibrary/images/english/1015.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-text">
                    <h3> Since 1861</h3>
                    <p>tdasdsdsdasd</p>
                    <p>asdasdasdas</p>
                    <p>asdaasd</p>
                    <button class="timeline-next">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**
little improvement with css classes

Answer (score 0):

You click event is applying the fadeout and fade in to all the nodes with a `timeline-item` class, you need to change the event handler to only apply the behavior in question to the parent of the clicked button. You can achieve this by doing :

```
$('.timeline-next').click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".timeline-item").fadeOut().next(".timeline-item").removeClass('hidden').fadeIn();
});
```